# SNMP protocol insert value or data to PostgreSQL Database Table

Tags: php, postgresql, protocols, snmp

First of all thank you to reach and read my question.
Level Difficult : Very Hard. :)

In one cabinet have 4 sensors, It is Tel-co Communication Cabinet that placed in higher location such as (hills, mountains and top building) we have 1000 cabinet  placed over my country Malaysia.

The 4 sensor such as :-

1. Humidity Sensor Inside Cabin
2. Humidity Sensor Outside Cabin
3. Temperature Inside Cabin
4. Temperature Outside Cabin

All 4 sensor required to sending value (every 15 minute) to database server currently **I am used PostgreSQL and running OS Windows Server**

Our Tel-Co (is our Client) provide a port from Card Controller Device through Lan Cable RJ45 to used SNMP Protocol. **I dont need to care about the Card Controller/Electrical Device it is not my development, I only work with them**

My objective is What or How to POST or Store the value of sensor to PostgreSQL using SNMP protocol. I already read about SNMP protocol, All explained in theory.

below is a Table Structure that i build in PostgreSQL

1. dvc_id *//device cabinet ID*
2. humscr_in *//Humidity Sensor Inside Cabin*
3. humscr_out *//Humidity Sensor Outside Cabin*
4. temp_in *//Temperature Inside Cabin*
5. temp_out *//Temperature Outside Cabin*
6. modfdate *//DateTimeWithoutTimeZone use to capture interval date every 15 minute*

**BELOW IS AN OUTPUT, WHEN QUERY VALUE FROM PostgreSQL**

10001 23 53 10 36 2017-03-25 15:15:00

10005 23 53 10 36 2017-03-25 15:15:00

10003 23 53 10 36 2017-03-25 15:15:00

10008 23 53 10 36 2017-03-25 15:15:00

10009 23 53 10 36 2017-03-25 15:15:00

> **I WANT TO KNOW HOW TO PROGRAM OR CONFIGURE OR INSTALL SNMP protocol SO THAT THE SENSOR WILL SEND VALUE AND INSERT INTO PostgreSQL, AS A CLIENT REQUIREMENT MUST USE SNMP PROTOCOL.**

Please explain me steps by step because I am PHP Programmer. not all i know. I only web based program. advise me if i should hire someone else to sit down together with me. If im hire someone, what is work of scope or what position or role im required to hire that someone. What to To call? IT engineer? Computer Engineer? or else???

Comment: Whilst voting to close, I will add this. I would normally expect that you have to issue an SNMP Get request to each cabinet (SNMP agent), specifying the OID of your variable you're interested in. That will give you the variable's value, and you can then insert each into your db. I would investigate any SNMP agent API (and/or you can do this via command line snmpget/snmpwalk binaries)

Comment: binaries? 101101110011 that what u mean?